# My Custom Routing Is Not Working in Codeigniter 3

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

Hi my custom routing is not working. When i type http://localhost/sitename the default_controller routing is working but when i type http://localhost/sitename/test the browser output is 404 not found. Please help me thank you.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Traffic/test';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['test'] = "Traffic/test";
```

Comment: you added a base url ?

Comment: did you enable rewrite_module for apache ?

Comment: Thank you its working now i just replace the .htaccess with the right one

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code on the routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['test'] = 'traffic/test'; 
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to rename my default controller php file to lowercase and the controller class name to lowercase and everything started to work.
When CI looks for the default controller file, it searches in lowercase for the file; 
if I name my controller file "Traffic/test" instead of "traffic/test"

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'traffic/test';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['test'] = "traffic/test";
```

now above code copy and paste your `routes.php`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `$route['default_controller']` expects a **controller** not a controller/method pair. The first thing you need to do is change that to `$route['default_controller'] = 'traffic';`

You may have some success using a controller/method pair, but you may run into trouble in the future as your routing increases in complexity.

also, as someone else already noted, Codeigniter naming and case convention must be followed: Even though the controller filename is uppercase  (i.e., `Traffic.php`) and the controller class is uppercase too (`class Traffic extends CI_Controller`) whenever you make a reference to the controller such as in the `default_controller` route, you must go all lowercase.

That said, your correct routing configuration should be:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'traffic';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['test'] = "traffic/test";
```

With this configuration:

- Browsing to `example.com` will load https://example.com/traffic/index
- Browsing to `example.com/test` will load https://example.com/traffic/test
- Browsing to any other URI will attempt to load the controller/method pair according to standard Codeigniter routing (i.e., example.com/something/trial will load the `something` controller and the `trial` method within the former)